# Common factor with radio button/textbox/combobox/datetimepicker

Tags: c#, return-value

I have multiple controls, each control with a different number of controls. I't trying to serialize the "Values" of each control into xml with the control name and the control "state".

```
For a textbox it would be textbox.Text,
For a radiobutton it would be radiobutton.Checked,
for a DateTimePicker it would be DateTimePicker.value
```

Is there a common factor or a conventional method to get these different words for "State" in a common way without a case statement.

Comment: Those are all properties created on each class, not from a base class or interface. So there is no link between them.

Comment: I assume you're talking about WinForms. (You should tag your question with the technology you're asking about.) Anyway, in theory it would be possible if you developed your own set of controls. For example, the Developer Express WinForms product's XtraEditors Library is built up like this, where all of the controls have a Value property that is of type Object.

Comment: right, we have some custom controls, and im looping through custom controls intermixed with basic controls, and was just wondering if instead of a 15 part case statement i could do it simpler

Answer (score 1):

There isn't, and for good reason -- all of those data values have different types, and are defined by the child class (so they aren't defined by a common interface).

Let's assume for the sake of argument that there *is* a way to get that value (say, as a function: `object getValue(Control control)`). If you wanted to use the return value of this function, then you would have to use a `case` statement anyway to get its type and use it correctly!

So just have a `case` statement.

Comment: There would be a way if all (or some) would share the same interface. But they do not. In webforms there is for example the [`ITextControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.itextcontrol(v=vs.100).aspx) which is implemented by TextBox and other controls. There you could cast them and use the `Text`-property.

Comment: while you are right Jashaszun, for this porpose everything is being converted into strings to be stored in xml, so different value types wouldn'nt be a relevant problem.

Comment: @CalvinSmith Ah right of course... however, in most cases this would be a problem.

Comment: @Jashaszun which explains why it is not supported, who on earth would want to do it..lol. Theres so many different/better solutions, but sometimes you just do what your told